# Is it possible to match with what comes after a character in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, if-statement, conditional-statements, match, aggregation

I'm trying to make a `match` aggregation query to my mongoDB. If th string I'm trying to match has a backslash it should only match on whatever is behind the backslash.

For example, if the string in the database is `Mike\Peter` i only want to match on `Peter`.

```
$match {
  'name': 'Peter'
}
```

Obviously this query will not match because `Mike\Peter` does not match `Peter`, so are there any way to check if the string contains `\` and if so, then only match with what comes after?

Comment: How do you get the input string Peter? Should it work for all such strings or the given input string?

Comment: You can use MongoDB regex query.

Comment: @prasad_ How do I do that though...

Comment: @Gibbs The input string comes from the REST endpoint. So I have a client that puts something into an input field. Whatever the client puts in, it is sent to the REST endpoint in the backend and I then take that input and feed it into the query.

Comment: See MongoDB [regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) usage. You need to provide the appropriate regex pattern for matching.

Comment: So `Peter` comes in on the API.   We know we want to match on `Mike\Peter`.  What if the name is just `Peter`?   Match or no match?

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti Match. Meaning if there is no `\` then we just do a normal match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `$regex` and escape the special character.

[Sample](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Xku8jCfQGx0)

```
[
  {
    "key": "Mike\\Peter"
  },
  {
    "key": "Peter"
  }
]

db.collection.find({
  key: {
    "$regex": "\\\\Peter"
  }
})
```